# function to create new column with defined parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the problem is i can't think of a way to get the 'mark' from the last day of the previous month.
because I need to compare the current month with the previous month
It's a number generated every day, Mark_LastDayData takes as reference the mark of the last day of the month and replaces it in all values ​​of that same month. 'Mark_LastDayDate_PreviousMonth' 4 it would be like getting the 'Mark_LastDayData' from the previous month so I can make a comparison in the future

I have the following DF

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BMonthEnd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Found':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
           'Date':['14/10/2021','19/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021','20/09/2021','20/10/2021','29/10/2021','15/10/2021'],
           #'LastDayMonth':['29/10/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021','30/09/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021','29/10/2021'],
           'Mark':[1,2,3,4,3,1,2,3]

          })
print(df)
```

**LastDayMonth was obtained through the code
I made some changes to the date

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
df['LastDayDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + BMonthEnd(0)
df['LastDayDatePrevMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
```

[image]

I needed the 'Mark' of the last day of the month of each date so I used the method

```
df = df.merge(df.loc[df['Date'] == df['LastDayDate'], ['Found','LastDayDate','Mark']],
     on=['Found', 'LastDayDate'],
     how='left', suffixes=['', '_LastDayDate'])
```

[image]

How can I do this to get the 'mark' from the last day of the previous month
in the same column

Sample df that I filled in manually

[image]

Comment: What is a "mark"? What is the first `Mark_LastDayDate_PreviousMonth` 4?

Comment: It's a number generated every day, Mark_LastDayData takes as reference the mark of the last day of the month and replaces it in all values ​​of that same month. 'Mark_LastDayDate_PreviousMonth' 4 it would be like getting the 'Mark_LastDayData' from the previous month so I can make a comparison in the future